# granting ALTER command access to Postgres RDS DB user

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, alter

I have created an user with read and write access in RDS database

But I am unable to grant ALTER access on table, getting permission denied error

Alter command is getting access denied issue.

And GRANT command doesn't gives option to give ALTER access to a table.

Is there any other command to give ALTER access to user?

I tried below command:

```
GRANT ALTER ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO read_write;
```

Got below error

> ERROR:  unrecognized privilege type "alter"

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using for the 'alter' command is incorrect. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
GRANT { { SET | ALTER SYSTEM } [, ... ] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
ON PARAMETER configuration_parameter [, ...]
TO role_specification [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
[ GRANTED BY role_specification ]
```

If you want to grant access to a user on all the table, you can do it like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name  TO database_name_app,database_name_developer;
```

You can read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html) for more details.